# Android Smart Watch - Full and small Screen mode - control programatically

Tags: android

I am developing android apps for Smart watches with Android 5.1 OS - Circular display. In all the models of the smart watch, they have full and small screen mode.

All the downloaded apps can be switched between these modes. **But the system apps like alarm, calendar will always be at full screen irrespective of the mode selected.**

> I want to add this restriction to my android apps. It should always
>   display in full screen irrespective of mode selected.

**Please guide me on how it works and how to achieve this.**

For reference, I have added some screen shots of both the modes.

In small screen mode, the apps open as small display at center

[image]

In full screen mode, the apps open as full display fitting the entire screen.

[image]

When we use the apps developed for mobile, we cannot the use the options at the corners. So we have to switch to small screen.

Comment: are you talking about the Android Wear devices, or about the Android phone, which is inserted in the watch-like shape? That is a huge difference

Comment: **Android phone** in the form of watch. It has Android 5.1 Lollipop OS.

Comment: well, then you have to search for the API for your specific watch-phone model. There is no unified API for all of them.